# Asp Net Core select list

Tags: asp.net-core

I have the following issue:

```
public class ShortInfo
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string FullName { get; }
}

public class SelectSomething
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<ShortInfo> Info { get; set; }
}
```

In the shared folder i have this partial view:

```
@model SelectSomething

<select asp-for="Id" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Info, "Id", 
"FullName"))"></select>
```

The partial view is displaying a list, and everything is working properly.

But, if try to execute the controller code, from a link like this one:

```
@Url.Action("Controller","Action", new { id = Model.Id })
```

Instead of this one

```
@Url.Action("Controller","Action")
```

I have two different result.

When the list from the partial view is created, it display the same exact content like before, but it automatically set the default value based on the id number.

For example, if i get to this view from a @Url.Action without no extra parameter, the list is a list of 4 elements, and the default one is the first one.

If i click on the link :

```
@Url.Action("Controller","Action", new { id = Model.Id })
```

I get the exact same list, but the default value being displayed is the index of Model.Id.

Can anyone help me to understand what is going on here, Thanks.

Comment: Please share code for your action methods  which are invoked  using Controller/Action and  Controller/Action/Id routes respectively.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have added `asp-for="Id"` on select tag, so that means that this select will be the value of Id. So everytime you provide the Id on route it will take effect on selected item.